# how to trigger jenkins downstream job irrespective upstream job status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-cli

Have configured parameter build plugin, to check for build status 
worst=failure and best=success then execute shell but its not triggering downstream job (it triggers only if upstream is success).

Could you plz suggest what is the best way to trigger jenkins downstream job irrespective upstream job status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I think the solution is to not have your upstream job failed in the first place, you can still handle failed downstream jobs with the help of i.e. env. variables or other means.

---

More information on the exact layout of your job would be helpful, however you can easily define how the result of your downstream job affects the upstream job.

### As a Build step

Handy when you have one wrapper job that triggers multiple downstream jobs and to i.e. aggregates some results, you can easily specify how the result of a downstream job affects the wrapper job.

You just need to check the *Block until the triggered projects finish their builds* to have this option show up.

[image]

---

The aviable options are explained as follows:

[image]

### As a Post-build action

This is for *chaining* jobs to run after another, allowing you to specify the run condition
[image]

Comment: Thanks very much i will try this and update tomorrow

Comment: Edited something in for clarification, key is to not have upstream job fail in the first place. You can still get the information of your downstream job status. Good luck!

Comment: for some reason, above still didnt work for me. May be I'm still missing something. However I tried "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" post build action and set "Trigger when build is=Complete (always)" and build without parameters. that worked for me.

Comment: Odd, however your solution is fine when you just need a chain of jobs, i added it to the answer for completeness.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CADq.png)
you can select the option (build after other projects build)..in the below you have three options..you can go with whatever option you want.just the last option for your requirement.